# Logstash in Elastic to execute the index policy

Tags: elasticsearch, version, metadata, metricbeat, elastic-beats

I am asking for help in this matter, the data stream from Logstash sends data in index format for example `okd-%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-2023.10.31`
I set up an index template in Elastic with the name okd, index patterns set to `okd-*-*-*` , ILM - name - okd - hot 1d, delete - 2d
I get the error:

> illegal_argument_exception: index.lifecycle.rollover_alias `[okd-*-*-*]`
> does not point to index
> [okd-%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-2023.10.31]

What am I doing wrong?
I tried to do it with different aliases, it still doesn't work, it doesn't create a file according to the alias and doesn't execute the life policy
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrTZP.jpg)

Comment: it seems that your documents do not contain any `[@metadata][beat]` and `[@metadata][version]` fields (i.e. they do not come from any Beats, as you have http and tcp inputs), so the index name is not the one you expect since those fields could not be resolved to actual values. Also you should simply use an index pattern like `okd-*`, no need for multiple wildcards

Comment: Well, I changed the template to okd-*, but what do I need to do to check what data should be, I am a beginner in this matter. If you can tell in more detail? thank you

Comment: You can simply name your index `okd-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}` in Logstash and your template will work

Comment: I will try now and I add PUT /_template/okd
{
  "index_patterns": ["okd-*"],
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "index.lifecycle.name": "okd",
    "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias": "okd"
  }
}

Comment: Please tell me how to check the creation of a new index today and the execution of the policy if the index was created today, thank you

Comment: Just try to run `GET _cat/indices/okd*` in Dev Tools and see if your new index is there

Comment: no create a new index in the format okd-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}, I have error illegal_argument_exception: rollover target [okd] does not point to a write index

Comment: What do you get when running `GET_cat/aliases/okd*?v` ?

Comment: okdn-%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-2023.10.30           okd-%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-2023.10.30 -      -             -              -
okd                                                                    okd-2023.04.17

Comment: There is still different data, but I can't reset it because the chat doesn't allow it

Comment: is it possible to leave the indexes that are for okd and untie the index templates and life policies from them, and do everything anew

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your documents do not contain any `[@metadata][beat]` and `[@metadata][version]` fields (i.e. they do not come from any Beats, as you have http and tcp inputs), so the index name is not the one you expect since those fields could not be resolved to actual values.

You should simply create an index named `okd-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}` use an index pattern like `okd-*`, no need for multiple wildcards.

You'll also need to change the `okd` alias to point to this new index, you can do it like this:

```
# create the new index
PUT okd-2023.11.01

# clean up aliases
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "remove": {
        "index": "okd-*",
        "alias": "okd"
      }
    },
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "okd-2023.11.01",
        "alias": "okd"
      }
    }
  ]
}

# remove the lifecycle policies from the old indexes
# note: the index name must be URL-encoded because of the special characters
POST okd-%25%7B%5B%40metadata%5D%5Bbeat%5D%7D-%25%7B%5B%40metadata%5D%5Bversion%5D%7D-*/_ilm/remove
```

Try it out and let's see where that leads.

Comment: Created a new index according to your code, removed all POST okd--*/_ilm/remove for old indexes, format okd-%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-*/_ilm /remove and POST okd-2023.04.18/_ilm/remove POST okd-2023.04.17/_ilm/remove
now there is a new index with a ilm policy of 1 day or 2 days of deletion, but the only thing in this index shows yellow open okd-2023.11.01 h1gcOVXbT1CEkq2ctkejug 3 2 0 0 678b 678b
there is no number of documents

Comment: It worked, a new index was created for today's number, I will still wait for the result of the life policy. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped!

Comment: Feel free to accept if it helped ;-)

Comment: Oh yes, of course, because since there can be many indexes per day, ILM requires you to add a increasing sequence number at the end of the index name. You would be better off setting up using a data stream name (without date and sequence number) in Logstash and let the data stream + ILM handle the roll overs